# Apply a widget to a DOM element on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to use a string to generate a jQuery UI widget on the fly?

It's easy to do this:

```
$(function() {
  $("selector").widget()    
})
```

What I want to do is something this:

```
ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (ajax.readyState==4 && ajax.status==200) {
    widget = ajax.responseText // widgetType is a string
    $("selector").widget() // but I want to use the *value* of widget
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foo.bar` is equivalent to `foo['bar']`.

Likewise, `$("selector").widget()` is equivalent to `$("selector")['widget']()`.

So you can write this:

```
ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (ajax.readyState==4 && ajax.status==200) {
    widgetType = ajax.responseText;
    $("selector")[widgetType]();
  }
}
```